# Couldn't find "contains" function in "purrr" package in R

Tags: r, contains, purrr

Currently I have R version 3.4.1 with "purrr" package version 0.2.3. The problem that I'm having is the "purrr" package doesn't have "contains" function and whenever I try to use "contains" function, it just gives me the "contains" function from "dplyr" package. How do I get "contains" function in "purrr" package?

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/217

Comment: Deleted my answer.  My version of `purrr` was old.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the conflict with `dplyr`, `contains()` was renamed in `purr` to `has_element()`, so you should use the latter.

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer as correct so that others can find it.